# How can I convert a SACAA (South Africa) AME license into a Belgium (EASA) licence?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, easa-regulations, south-africa

I have a SACAA (South Africa) AME license and would like to convert it into a Belgium EASA licence part 66. What are the steps to follow?

Comment: Have you asked if South Africa has bilateral agreements for AME licensing reciprocity with EASA and/or Belgium?